# Can't retrieve the info after downloading this data

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to access the data downloaded from a website which looks like this:

```
{"quizzes":[
{"id":1, "question": "Can't solve this :("},
{"id":2, "question": "Someone help pls"}]}
```

The data downloaded looks way more complex, with more values, more keys, and some keys being associated to another dictionary of Key:String, but since I can't even access the most simple fields I thought I would start with this.

I'm using JSONSerialization, so my question is:

If I want to create a variable where i can save the downloaded data... Which would be it's type? I would say [String:[String:Any]], but I'm not sure if "quizzes" represents a key on this specific key, since the data starts with '{' and not with '['.

Comment: i have no resource to write swift 2  , the answer is in NSCoding

Comment: Have you actually tried this? Personally I would go for the more generic format [String:Any] and have runtime check the structure of the data as it is parsed

Comment: Your data type should be `[String:[[String:Any]]]`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JSONSerialization one could use JSONDecoder.

**Example**

```
struct Question: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let question: String
}

struct Quiz: Decodable {
    let quizzes: [Question]
}
```

Assuming jsonStr is a string with the JSON in your question:

```
if let jsonData = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8) {
    if let quiz = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Quiz.self, from: jsonData) {
        for question in quiz.quizzes {
            print("\(question.id) \"\(question.question)\"")
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1 "Can't solve this :("
2 "Someone help pls"
```